# How to set up "Submit email" form

Tags: email

Im complete novice to web design. My question is, what do I need to set up in order to have "Submit email" form on Coming soon page for updates? Can I direct the message and email to an already existing email address? Or do I need to set up a database on the hosting server? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Just put a mailto: link in the page with the e-mail address and allow people to get in touch that way
- or Setup a  on the page and then use server side coding (such as PHPs mail function) to send an e-mail out when this form is submitted. Exact details on how to do that would depend on what your web server is capable of supporting and how complex a form you wanted to use. You don't need a database running on the server to do this.

With both approaches you need to be careful with spam though as you don't want crawlers to be picking up the e-mail address.